# Can i have 2 ER diagrams for one database

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

The database I have set up is accessed by normal users and an admin with both user types having different permissions. Should I have 2 ER diagrams? The relationships I've worked out are as follows:

`````
user m books n bookings
user m views n fixtures
user m creates n orders
user m views n results
user m creates 1 user

admin 1 adds m blogs
admin 1 manages m bookings
admin 1 adds m fixtures
admin 1 creates m orders
admin 1 updates m results
admin 1 creates 1 user ````
`````

Comment: Do you mean users in your DBMS or users in your application?

Comment: Those are not relationships/relations/associations. They are cardinalities of binary relationships that you haven't clearly given.  Eg "user U views fixture F" is M:N in U:F. Relationships that are often only being used to describe yet other n-ary relationships (that they are projections of) that are the ones you will actually characterize your situations by & have tables for that you haven't clearly given. Eg "booking B is user U bookning fixture F got timeslot T". (I don't mean that you need to give them to ask your question here.)